# __autoload() equivalent for non-class functions?

Tags: php

I keep running into issues where I want to use a useful function like `str_getcsv()` or `quoted_printable_encode()`, but find that it only came into being between as of PHP 5.3. I want to have this code I'm writing be compatible with at least 5.2, but I don't want to have to write a bunch of specialized code.

I've gotten into the habit grabbing stand-in functions from the PHP.net comments, storing them in helpfully-named files like `func.quoted_printable_encode.php`, and writing a block like the below in each place I want to invoke them.

```
if( ! function_exists('quoted_printable_encode') ) {
    $funcfile = 'func.quoted_printable_encode.php';
    if( file_exists($funcfile) && is_readable($funcfile) ) {
        require('func.quoted_printable_encode.php');
    } else {
        Throw new Exception('Cannot invoke function: quoted_printable_encode');
    }
}
```

This seems eerily similar to `__autoload()` for classes, and `__call()` for object methods, but I can't find anything regarding global functions. Does such a thing exist, or do I have to shoehorn all these extra functions into a header file somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to autoload functions in PHP. There is [an RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/autofunc) but it has not been implemented (and it probably will not be).

If you really want to autoload functions then it may make sense to create a helper class where you implement the functions as static methods. It is [quite](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Arr) [common](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/array_helper.html) in frameworks to do it like that.